# Add generated build file to classpath

Tags: java, maven-2

During my build I generate a build.properties files via the maven properties plugin (properties-maven-plugin) containing build information.

What's the best way to have this file included in the generated jar? I don't want to put it into the src/main/resources directory as this would pollute my default resource directory.

Is there not a "generated-resources" directory as there is with source?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I thought there was a default `generated-resources` directory, but I can't find any documentation on that at the moment. You can always configure additional resource directories in your pom:

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>${project.build.directory}/generated-resources</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    ...
</build>
```

Answer (score 1):

Place generated sources in target/generated-sources

There is a plugin called [build-helper](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/) that allows you to add that folder to the source-folders list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use maven assembly plugin to organize files and filesets in packages. have a look at http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/advanced-descriptor-topics.html
I think it is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

you can output your files to any directory and add that resource directory to your `<resources>` of your `<build>`

Answer (score -4):

You should put it in the `target/classes` directory

(fixed now from just target) and I think that this is better than the accepted one. As there is no need to process this resource as resource anymore