# IntelliJ maven project generated-sources not picked up (only some)

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I've reinstalled my windows machine and installed Java 13, Maven 3.6.2 to finally run my projects. I use java immutable classes which get generated by maven. I have a problem where only SOME generated sources are picked up and some are missing in the editor (shows errors). However, I'm able to run the application through IntelliJ and build with Maven.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Do note that I've gone through a number of similar questions where ALL generated-sources are not picked up and I have the correct settings for picking up source files.

[image]

Comment: Please report at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/requests/new with a sample project to reproduce the issue.

Comment: have you tried something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9292908/add-generated-build-file-to-classpath ? And this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5170620/unable-to-use-intellij-with-a-generated-sources-folder ? (also check if you are using the existing path of those generated sources)

Comment: You haven't read the question @itwasntme

Comment: @CrazyCoder that's my last resort at the moment, but if I really can't find the answer I will create an issue there - thanks

Comment: I did... when looking for this link I also found a bunch of resources on other sites, but I'm guessing you've also read them. Could you provide more details about your current project configuration, structure and pom? (Probably I won't be able to answer but others might)

Answer (score 0):

Kind of a funny situation here... Everything worked fine, but I found that one of the interfaces I used (from which a generated source is made) had another generated source marked as red (as if not imported). Importing the full path for it suddenly resolved the issue.

```
common.advert.Price getPrice();
```

My guess this is an editor problem that I have.